# mysql from_days producing unexpected result

Tags: mysql, function

I am trying to get the number of months and days between different dates but am getting an unexpected result of 0months, 0 days from mysql. The sql query am running is:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( FROM_DAYS( TO_DAYS( NOW() ) - TO_DAYS( '2016-01-01' ) ), '%c months, %e days') as months_days
```

and the result is:

```
+++++++++++++++
month_days
+++++++++++++++
0 months, 0days
```

What could be the cause of this and is there another way around this?

Comment: Difference in months is not very well defined.  Provide some examples of what results you want to get.  Pay particular attention to the beginning and ending of months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check these 2 functions:

For Months : [Period Diff](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_period-diff)
For days : [Date Diff](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)

Comment: Thank you @sourcecode, the functions gave me just what i needed.